# How to call another service variable data in any service/controller using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http.get('/GetData').then(function(response) {
$scope.lastTimeStamp  = response.data.result[1].timestamp;
    var timeStamp = moment($scope.lastTimeStamp,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        if($scope.lastTimeStamp!=undefined && $scope.lastTimeStamp!=''){
            $scope.lastTimeStamp = $scope.lastTimeStamp;
        } else {
            $scope.lastTimeStamp = '';
    }
}
```

So, This timeStamp value I want in another service call in different page.How I can call this timeStamp and display there?

I am not much friendly to coding..Please help.

Comment: You're referencing on the same variable -> $scope.lastTimeStamp = $scope.lastTimeStamp . Suppose to be $scope.lastTimeStamp = timeStamp

Comment: yes but how to call in another controller?

Comment: for temporary movement you can use localstorage

Comment: can u pls show with code

Comment: @TB.M use $rootScope to share it in another controller, view example in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for data sharing across the controller in `angular JS` you can use localstorge, sessionstorage or $rootScope

way to share data through localstorage :

```
localStorage.setItem('title', $scope.title);
// Retrieve the title
$scope.title = localStorage.getItem('title');
```

way to share data through sessionStorage:

```
 sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);

 // to get the data 

 sessionStorage.getItem(key, value);
```

way to share data through rootScope:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.run(function($rootScope) {
         $rootScope.userData = {};
         $rootScope.userData.firstName = "Ravi";
         $rootScope.userData.lastName = "Sharma";
      });


      app.controller("firstController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
           console.log($rootScope.userData.firstName)
      });
```